# Image matching a simple image in opencv. Is haar cascading overkill?

Tags: ios, opencv

I am very new to CV, and I am trying to check for an image in a snapshot in an iphone app, something very simple (like an overly simple QR code -- I only need to really know if it is one of two images). The concept is to play "laser tag" with an iphone camera. If someone is wearing a badge, I want to know they badge is there, and which badge it is. This should be adjusted for lighting and affine transformations.  It seems like scaling with template matching might not be strong enough (even though the image could be whatever I want it to be) due to affine transformations and lighting issues. Something like haar cascading seems like big overkill, but I am very new to CV, so I really don't know where to start, or if this process will be necessary. Any advice about the tradeoffs of the various ways to approach this problem would be helpful. What OpenCV methods are going to be helpful, and which ones will probably not work? What designs would be easiest to detect for to denote the two teams. Encoding more data than two teams would be great, but not necessary for now.

A much stronger version of what I need to do is implemented in the [Plickers](https://plickers.com/) app, so insight on how you think that is done with opencv would be helpful.